# Remove a char in string and then use dictionary to do key match

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

I want write a function to convert string to float by using map and reduce. (no int() here).
Here is my code so far:

```
from functools import reduce

def str2float(s):
    def char2number(s):
        s = s.replace('.', '')
        return {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}[s] #here i try to get pure numbers 

    def find_digt(s):
        return (len(s) - s.find('.') - 1) if ',' in s else 0

    return reduce(lambda x, y: (10 * x + y), (map(char2number, s))) / pow(10, find_digt(s))


print(str2float('1456.124'))
```

So after this, I get an error:

```
return {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}[sn]  # [s] is the [key]
KeyError: ''
```

Which means that the '' is not in the dict. I did some test like:

```
s = '1234.456'
s = s.replace(',', '')
print('' in s) #True
```

So the question now is, once

```
s = s.replace('.', '')
```

the '.' replace by '', it did not clear the '.' in the string.

I'm wondering what is going on here. what is the right way to clear a char in a string since it is immutable.

Comment: Did you intentionally check `if ',' in s` but then search for the index of `.`? It seems like that's a left-over where you had another seperator. But that's definetly odd.

Comment: it should be '.'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you iterate with `map` over the *unaltered* input string because you only remove the `.` in the `char2number` function. Outside of the function the replacement didn't happen.

I would suggest doing the finding the position and replacing it immediatly:

```
from functools import reduce

def str2float(s):
    pos_decimal_point = (len(s) - s.find('.') - 1) if '.' in s else 0
    s = s.replace('.', '')

    def char2number(s):
        return {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}[s] #here i try to get pure numbers 

    return reduce(lambda x, y: (10 * x + y), 
                  (map(char2number, s))) / pow(10, pos_decimal_point)


print(str2float('1456.124'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a trivial tracing statement:

```
def char2number(s):
    print ("ENTER", s)
    s = s.replace('.', '')
    return {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}[s]
```

Output:

```
ENTER 1
ENTER 4
ENTER 5
ENTER 6
ENTER .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(str2float('1456.124'))
  File "so.py", line 12, in str2float
    return reduce(lambda x, y: (10 * x + y), (map(char2number, s))) / pow(10, find_digt(s))
  File "so.py", line 7, in char2number
    return {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}[s] #here i try to get pure numbers 
KeyError: ''
```

You pass individual characters of '1234.456' to `char2number`.  When you pass the dot, the replace *does* clear it out, and you're left with a null string.

I'm not sure how you intend this to work.  Your seems to expect the entire string sent to the support functions.  however, `map` works on the sequence of elements in an iterable.

As for changing a string, you can't, really: you did what we *can* do, assigning the output of `replace` back to the original string.  The problem you had was simply that it operates on a single character at that point in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea, just replace the `.` in `s` before passing to your `map` function:

```
map(char2number, s.replace('.',''))
```

Note: There's a typo in `find_digt()`, it should read: `if '.' in s...`.
If you also want to handle commas, add an extra `replace` to knock them out:

```
stripped_s = s.replace('.','').replace(',','')
return reduce(lambda x, y: (10 * x + y), (map(char2number, stripped_s))) / pow(10, find_digt(s))

print(str2float('1,456.124'))
1456.124
```

Full code:

```
def str2float(s):
    def char2number(s):
        return {'0': 0, '1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9}[s]  

    def find_digt(s):
        return (len(s) - s.find('.') - 1) if '.' in s else 0

    stripped_s = s.replace('.','').replace(',','')
    return reduce(lambda x, y: (10 * x + y), (map(char2number, stripped_s))) / pow(10, find_digt(s))

    print(str2float('1,456.124'))
    1456.124
```